# How do I split up Touch UI dialog files?

Tags: xml, aem

I'm not sure what to put at the beginning of each tab file. I'm trying to split up "Basic" and "Advance" into there own tabs for example tab_basic and tab_advance. I'm not sure if I'm suppose to use (jcr:root,content,layout, and items) at the beginning of each tab file and if so how do I properly do that?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
<content
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
    <layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
        type="nav"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <basic
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Basic"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
            <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <columns
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <basic
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <title
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldLabel="Title"
                                    name="./jcr:title"/>
                                <canonicalUrl
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldDescription="Enter the proper canonical Url.e.g.http://example.com/page.html"
                                    fieldLabel="Canonical Url"
                                    name="./canonicalUrl"/>
                                <tags
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete"
                                    fieldLabel="Tags/Keywords"
                                    multiple="{Boolean}true"
                                    name="./cq:tags">
                                    <datasource
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/common/datasources/tags"/>
                                    <values
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete/tags"/>
                                    <options
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete/list"/>
                                </tags>
                                <hideinnav
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./hideInNav"
                                    text="Hide in Navigation"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <hideinnav-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./hideInNav@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <newwindow
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    fieldDescription="Decides whether the link in the secondary navigation opens in a new window."
                                    name="./newwindow"
                                    text="New Window from Secondary Navigation"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <newwindow-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./newwindow@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <hideinFooter
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./hideinFooter"
                                    text="Hide in Footer"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <hideinfooter-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./hideinFooter@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <disableNavLink
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./disableNavLink"
                                    text="Disable link in Sitemap"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <disablenavlink-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./disableNavLink@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <headerfooter
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./headerfooter"
                                    text="Header / Footer OFF"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <headerfooter-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./headerfooter@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <livechat
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./livechat"
                                    text="Live Chat OFF"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <livechat-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./livechat@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <headerView
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                                    fieldDescription="Select header and footer view to be displayed. By default, View1 will be displayed."
                                    fieldLabel="Header - Footer View"
                                    name="./headerView"
                                    value="view1">
                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                        <view1
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            text="View1"
                                            value="view1"/>
                                        <view2
                                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                            text="View2"
                                            value="view2"/>
                                    </items>
                                </headerView>
                                <disableMegaMenu
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    fieldDescription="Disable the showing of the mega-menu when hovering over navigation bar menu items"
                                    name="./disableMegaMenu"
                                    text="Disable MegaMenu"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <disablemegamenu-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./disableMegaMenu@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <disableSearch
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    fieldDescription="Disable the search box that appears in the nav drawer menu in mobile and tablet view"
                                    name="./disableNavSearch"
                                    text="Disable Nav Drawer Search"/>
                                <disablesearch-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./disableNavSearch@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <pagetheme
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete"
                                    fieldLabel="Theme Tag"
                                    multiple="{Boolean}true"
                                    name="./themetag">
                                    <datasource
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/common/datasources/tags"/>
                                    <values
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete/tags"/>
                                    <options
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/autocomplete/list"/>
                                </pagetheme>
                            </items>
                        </basic>
                        <more_titles
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="More Titles and Description"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="More Titles and Description">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <pagetitle
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldLabel="Page Title"
                                    name="./pageTitle"/>
                                <navtitle
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldLabel="Navigation Title"
                                    name="./navTitle"/>
                                <subtitle
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldLabel="Subtitle"
                                    name="./subtitle"/>
                                <description
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textarea"
                                    fieldLabel="Description"
                                    name="./jcr:description"/>
                            </items>
                        </more_titles>
                        <onofftime
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="On/Off Time"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="On/Off Time">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <ontime
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/datepicker"
                                    fieldLabel="On Time"
                                    name="./onTime"
                                    type="datetime"/>
                                <offtime
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/datepicker"
                                    fieldLabel="Off Time"
                                    name="./offTime"
                                    type="datetime"/>
                                <onTimeHint
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./onTime@TypeHint"
                                    value="Date"/>
                                <offTimeHint
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./offTime@TypeHint"
                                    value="Date"/>
                            </items>
                        </onofftime>
                        <vanity
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="Vanity URL"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="Vanity URL">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <vanityPath
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
                                    fieldLabel="Vanity URL">
                                    <field
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                        name="./sling:vanityPath"
                                        required="{Boolean}false"/>
                                </vanityPath>
                                <vanityPathRedirect
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./sling:redirect"
                                    text="Redirect Vanity URL"/>
                                <vanitypathredirect-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./sling:redirect@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                            </items>
                        </vanity>
                    </items>
                </columns>
            </items>
        </basic>
        <advanced
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            jcr:title="Advanced"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
            <layout
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <columns
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <custom
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <scrollMore
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    fieldDescription="Enable the 'scroll more' button on this page"
                                    name="./scrollMore"
                                    text="Enable Scroll More Button"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <scrollmore-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./scrollMore@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                            </items>
                        </custom>
                        <partner
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="Partner Sites"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="Partner Sites">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <isPartner
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    fieldDescription="Identify the page and its children pages as partner sites"
                                    name="./isPartner"
                                    text="Is Partner Site"/>
                                <ispartner-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./isPartner@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                            </items>
                        </partner>
                        <advanced
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <language
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                                    fieldLabel="Language"
                                    name="./jcr:language">
                                    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"/>
                                </language>
                                <redirect
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                    fieldLabel="Redirect"
                                    name="./redirectTarget"/>
                                <designpath
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                    fieldLabel="Design"
                                    name="./cq:designPath"
                                    rootPath="/etc/designs"/>
                                <styling
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                    fieldDescription="This includes the Look &amp; Feel of the page"
                                    fieldLabel="Styling"
                                    name="./cssPath"
                                    rootPath="/etc/designs"/>
                                <alias
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldLabel="Alias"
                                    name="./sling:alias"/>
                            </items>
                        </advanced>
                        <site-structure/>
                        <cug
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="Closed User Group"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="Closed User Group">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <enabled
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox"
                                    name="./cq:cugEnabled"
                                    text="Enabled"
                                    value="true"/>
                                <enabled-delete
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/hidden"
                                    name="./cq:cugEnabled@Delete"
                                    value="{Boolean}true"/>
                                <loginPage
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                    fieldLabel="Login Page"
                                    name="./cq:cugLoginPage"/>
                                <principals
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/multifield"
                                    fieldLabel="Admitted Groups">
                                    <field/>
                                </principals>
                                <realm
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldDescription="Leave empty to use the page title."
                                    fieldLabel="Realm"
                                    name="./cq:cugRealm"/>
                            </items>
                        </cug>
                        <export
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            jcr:title="Export"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/fieldset"
                            title="Export">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <template
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/pathbrowser"
                                    fieldLabel="Export Configuration"
                                    name="./cq:exportTemplate"
                                    rootPath="/etc/contentsync/templates"/>
                            </items>
                        </export>
                    </items>
                </columns>
            </items>
        </advanced>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might have to use two properties : `path` and `sling:resourceSuperType` inside the nt:unstructured node (tab item).Here is my content.xml for dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Sample Component"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:hideChildren="[column]">
            <fname
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="First Name"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                    margin="{Boolean}false"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <firstname
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldDescription="Mandatory"
                                fieldLabel="First Name"
                                name="./fname"/>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </fname>
            <mname
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    jcr:title="Middle Name"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
                        margin="{Boolean}false"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <middlename
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                    fieldDescription="Mandatory"
                                    fieldLabel="Middle Name"
                                    name="./mname"/>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </mname>
            <lname
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
                path="/apps/project/components/lname"/>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Here `/apps/project/components/lname` is the node referred as tab. Below is the content.xml for that node :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Last Name"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
    <layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
        margin="{Boolean}false"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <column
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <lname
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    fieldDescription="Mandatory"
                    fieldLabel="Last Name"
                    name="./lname"/>
            </items>
        </column>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

Here lname is the example, you can do it for tab_basic and tab_advance.